# Pyspark read json with json object with a list of json inside it change some formatting when converting to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pyspark, nested

I have the following list of json object:

```
[
  {
    "AccountId": "xxxx",
    "ResourceId": "yyyy",
    "ProductName": "zzzz",
    "Tags": [{"Name": "John Doe"}, {"Environment":"DEV"}]
  },
  {
    "AccountId": "aaaa",
    "ResourceId": "bbbb",
    "ProductName": "cccc",
    "Tags": [{"Name": "Jane Doe"}, {"Environment":"DEV"}]
  },
  {
    "AccountId": "iiii",
    "ResourceId": "jjjj",
    "ProductName": "kkkk",
    "Tags": [{"Environment":"QA"}]
  }
]
```

I tried making it into a dataframe using this way:

```
ss = SparkSession.builder.appName("PythonSpark2").getOrCreate()
sc = ss.sparkContext

jsonList = someFunctionToCreate()
jsonDf = ss.read.json(sc.parallelize(jsonList))
jsonDf.show(truncate=False)
```

The end result would mess up the 'Tags' column. The list of json object inside the array would be split into an array of an array with the value of the json value.

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|      AccountId      |     ResourceId   |     ProductName     |         Tags        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|        xxxx         |       yyyy       |        zzzz         | [[JohnDoe,],[,DEV]] |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|        aaaa         |       bbbb       |        cccc         | [[JaneDoe,],[,DEV]] |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|        iiii         |       jjjj       |        kkkk         |     [[,],[,QA]]     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

Is there a way for me to prevent this? Or am I using a bad structure for the json?

Comment: it is an array of struct column, I think and I think that is reasonable.

Comment: @Lamanus so it's expected, yes? Is there a better way to structure the json for this kind of use? I tried changing 'Tags' to be a comma separated strings, but it produces an _corrupt_record column when read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist a function simply makes the column to json, `to_json`.

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").json("test.json")
df.show(truncate=False)

df.withColumn('Tags', to_json('Tags')).show(truncate=False)

+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
|AccountId|ProductName|ResourceId|Tags                                       |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
|xxxx     |zzzz       |yyyy      |[{"Name":"John Doe"},{"Environment":"DEV"}]|
|aaaa     |cccc       |bbbb      |[{"Name":"Jane Doe"},{"Environment":"DEV"}]|
|iiii     |kkkk       |jjjj      |[{"Environment":"QA"}]                     |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: nice, it works like a charm. Thanks! I didn't know we can simple reformat it like that.